# Typescript: How to take subset of attributes from an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Example:

```
type t = {
  a1: boolean;
  a2: number;
  a3: string;
};

const o1 = {
  a1: true,
  a2: 1,
  a3: 'blah',
  a4: false,
  a5: 'blah blah'
}

const o2: t = o1 as t;  // this doesn't work as I expected
```

How to set o2 dynamically to take only o1's attributes which fit type t?

I.e., keep the attributes that fit and discard the rest. In this case with a result equivalent to

```
const o2: t = {
  a1: o1.a1,
  a2: o1.a2,
  a3: o1.a3
}
```

except done dynamically as t may change.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think TypeScript has anything built-in that lets you do this. It would require a form of reflection, which in turn would require TypeScript to emit a list of `t`'s members to the JavaScript it outputs, which it normally doesn't. I haven't found anything in the TypeScript documentation about reflection (which was surprising).

As a workaround, you could list the members in an array. This is duplication, but appears to be unavoidable duplication:

```
type t = {
  a1: boolean;
  a2: number;
  a3: string;
};
const t_members = ["a1", "a2", "a3"];
```

then it's a simple loop:

```
const o2: t = {} as t;
for (const member of t_members) {
    o2[member] = o1[member];
}
```

If this is something you do frequently, create a utility function for it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see Const o2 is becoming a type-of object instead of type t so it is taking all the properties that you are assigning,

here you can do one thing,
`

```
class t  {
  a1: boolean;
  a2: number;
    a3: string;
    constructor(a:any) {
        this.a1 = a.a1;
        this.a2 = a.a2;
        this.a3 = a.a3;
  }
};

type c={
     a1: boolean,
  a2: number,
  a3: string,
  a4: false,
  a5: string

}

const o1:c = {
  a1: true,
  a2: 1,
  a3: 'blah',
  a4: false,
  a5: 'blah blah'
}

let o2: t = new t(o1);
```

`

this might help.

Answer (score 0):

Make custom function and check:

```js
var t = {
  a1: 'boolean',
  a2: 'number',
  a3: 'string'
};

const o1 = {
  a1: true,
  a2: 1,
  a3: 'blah',
  a4: false,
  a5: 'blah blah'
}

function clone(obj,type) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var key in obj) {
    var val=obj[key];
    var exists=checkExists(type,key,val);
    if(exists)
    {
     if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) copy[key] = obj[key];
    }
       
    }
    return copy;
}

function checkExists(obj,oldkey,oldval){
var resp;
oldval=typeof(oldval);
for (var key in obj) {
    var val=obj[key];
        if(oldval==val) // use (oldkey==key && oldval==val) to check all key and val
        {
         resp = true;
         break;
        }else{
         resp = false;
        }
    }
    
    return resp;
}

var out=clone(o1,t);
console.log(out);
```